# groupby not working, TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I was trying to build a feature on this dataframe that allows me to see the cumulative sum of the goals of a team in only won games, done untile the picked game (this one included). You can assume that the rows are chronologically sorted.

Here is a dataframe sample with the code I was trying to use

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['Italy','Italy','UK','UK','UK'], 'Goals': [2, 2, 1, 4, 1], 'Won': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

data = data.assign(
    CumulativeGoalsInWonGames = data.groupby('Team', group_keys=False)[['Goals','Won']].apply(lambda s: (s.Goals*s.Won).cumsum())
)

data
```

It came out the following error

```
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

but I don't understand why. Also, I see that deleting the columns after the groupby works, as shown in the following code

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['Italy','Italy','UK','UK','UK'], 'Goals': [2, 2, 1, 4, 1], 'Won': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

data = data.assign(
    CumulativeGoalsInWonGames = data.groupby('Team', group_keys=False).apply(lambda s: (s.Goals*s.Won).cumsum())
)

data
```

Can someone helps me understand what's happening? Thanks